# Reordering items in Flatlist

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Is there a way to configure reordering of items in a Flatlist?  i.e. similar to what you can do in IOS TableView: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/ManageReorderRow/ManageReorderRow.html

(if not any points as to how react-native developers would then implement this?)

Comment: Haven't try it but seems to work fine: https://github.com/gitim/react-native-sortable-list